# Defining Custom ListView Rows with Adapters

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) to create custom rows for a list view. It worked when I followed the guide line by line, only changing names and a few details to accommodate for the different views in my own row. However I want to be able to add rows with the click of a button and therefor the array that is provided in the example won't work. I tried to create an ArrayList of type Requirement, which are defined by the class Requirement to replace the array used to create the adapter but it doesn't work. I can no longer open the intent to test out the button because it crashes when it tries to initialize the List View, the error being Null Pointer Exception.

I call this function in onCreate:

```
ArrayList<Requirement> req_data_list;
RequirementAdapter adapter;

private void initialize_listView(){
    req_data_list.add(new Requirement());
    RequirementAdapter adapter = new RequirementAdapter(this, R.layout.requirements_item, req_data_list);
    ListView req_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Requirement_listview);
    req_list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is the class for the elements of the ArratList:

```
public class Requirement{
    public String name,requirement_id,type,notes;// These variables will be implemented later, and correspond to elements not yet included.
    public int men, hours, elevation,req_count;
    public boolean breathing_air;

    public Requirement(){
        super();
    }

    public Requirement(int men_p, int hours_p, int elevation_p, int req_count_p, String name_p, 
        String requirement_id_p, String type_p, String notes_p, boolean breathing_air_p){
        super();
        //TODO this constructor will be defined later.
    }

}// Requirement
```

This is the class that defines the adapter:

```
public class RequirementAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Requirement>{
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Requirement> data = null;

public RequirementAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Requirement> data ){
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data=data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View row = convertView;
    RequirementHolder holder = null;
    if(row==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId,parent,false);

        holder = new RequirementHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Name_Text);
        holder.name_e = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.Name_Edit);
        holder.men = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.Men_But);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } // if

    else{
        holder = (RequirementHolder)row.getTag();
    } // else


    return row;

} // getView


static class RequirementHolder{
    TextView name;
    EditText name_e;
    Button men;
}
}
```

Finally this is the function to add new elements in the list view:

```
private void new_layout_element(){
    req_data_list.add(new Requirement());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

EDIT: If it helps, I found that if I change the array list back into an array, no matter how long the array is, only one element shows up.

Answer (score 0):

you dont set data  anywhere in your adapter to components of listitem.
use code same this in your adapter.

```
 holder.name.setText(data.get(position).name);
 holder.name_e.setText(data.get(position).name_e);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just be changing the text that appears when the list view is created? Also, when I add the line holder.name_e.setText(data.get(position).name_e); I get an error because I have no variable called name_e in my Requirement class.

Comment: yes you dont set text anywhere.use variable of Requirement class that you want display in holder.name_e instead of it

Comment: Okay, thanks. However is this necessary if I want the textview to always say "Name"?